# How to rank a new type of Hold 'Em Poker hand (hard)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games, poker

I am trying to figure out how to rank a new type of poker hand, henceforth called a 'Block'.

A Block consists of 6 cards, and so is not possible in regular Poker - only Hold'em.

Each Block consists of 2 sets of 3 consecutive cards, looping from Queen to Ace and ignoring Kings. Each Block uses the same numbers, in different colours (red and black).

For example: A '2' Block would consist of Ace, 2 and 3 of any combination of spades OR clubs, and A, 2, and 3 of hearts OR diamonds. In short, a red set and a matching black set.

A Looped Example: A 'Q' Block would consist of J, Q and Ace of (spades and/or clubs), and J, Q and Ace of (hearts and/or diamonds).

My brain melts when I attempt to calculate the odds, but here is my best attempt:

- So, there are 12 Blocks, each of which can be made in a bunch of ways (64?) - so 768 ways to make a block.
- A web search tells me there are 133,784,560 ways that 7 cards can peel from the top of a 52 card deck.
- 133,784,560 / 768 = 174,198

... So, if I'm at all in the region of correctness, the chances of forming a Block are very, very slim. Like, only 4 or 5 times more common than a straight flush, and slightly more rare than 4 of a kind (going off of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability#7-card_poker_hands).

So here are my questions:

1. How would a Block rank versus regular Hold 'Em hands? Aka, did I do the above math right (I almost certainly did not)?
2. If we add that Kings are wild, just for this particular hand, how much easier does achieving a Block become? [Trying to calculate this makes my eyes jitter - we can't reuse the kings but could use more than 1; brain hurty.]

... Thanks y'all.

Comment: In normal Texas Hold'em a  hand containing one of your blocks would be a hand with either two pairs or a full house.  Therefore the probabilities of those hands given by Wikipedia would have to be reduced  by an appropriate amount for your version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is almost correct; you're missing two points.  The first point is that you also need to count the possibilities for the seventh card, which could be any of the $46$ remaining cards.  So the number of possible "Block" hands is closer to $12\cdot 2^6 \cdot 46=35328$.  The second point is that some of these hands can form a "Block" in two ways; specifically, this happens when the seventh card is the same rank as any of the other six cards.  So the exact count is
$$
12\cdot \left(40\cdot 4^3 + 3 \cdot 4^3\right) = 33024,
$$
where the first term counts the hands consisting of a Block and a seventh card of a different rank (these are two-pair hands), and the second term counts the hands consisting of a Block with an extra card in one of the three ranks (these are full houses).  This gives a probability of
$$
\frac{33024}{133784560}\approx 0.0247\%;
$$
so a Block should beat a (non-royal) straight flush (being slightly less probable) and lose only to a royal flush.

Comment: A royal flush is just the highest straight flush. I would expect it to beat all the straight flushes if it's less probable.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Right, it just depends on whether you consider the royal flush to be a different type of hand than the other straight flushes.  It makes no difference in an actual game of poker, so I think it's a matter of taste.  In many video poker games, the royal flush has a different payoff, so there's at least some precedent for treating it as a separate type of hand.

Comment: In Texas Hold'em or (or $7$-card stud) the probability of getting a royal flush (namely $\ \frac{4\times{47\choose2}}{{52\choose7}}\ $) is slightly higher than that of getting any other *specific* smaller straight flush (namely $\ \frac{4\times{46\choose2}}{{52\choose7}}\ $) because the other two cards can be *any* of the remaining $47$ in the pack, whereas for lower straight flushes neither of them can be the card that would shift the straight up one place.

Comment: The probability of getting *any* non-royal straight flush is, of course,  $\ 
\frac{36{46\choose2}}{52\choose7}\ $, which is the probability that counts for the ranking of the hands.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm ill at the moment but once I'm recovered maybe I'll understand what you're saying 

Any thoughts on Question 2 - how the odds change if Kings are wild?

Comment: Question 2 is substantially trickier :).